# How can I get the next 6 days in a v-for loop in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, vuejs3

I have a specific date that I am wanting to then get the next 6 days (to have a week ahead type of component) for. I am thinking I can just have my initial date and then do a `v-for` range loop like:

```html
<span v-for="n in 7">{{ n }}</span>
```

where the first element would be the passed-in date. But I am not exactly sure what the best way to achieve this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to calculate the next 7 dates directly within the `<template>`:

```html
<span v-for="n in 7">{{ new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + n) }}</span>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-generate-week-ahead-yejp7t?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FWeekAhead.vue)

Alternatively, you could move that into `<script>` to declutter the `<template>`:

```html
<script setup>
const today = new Date()
const nextSevenDays = Array(7).fill().map((_, i) => new Date(today).setDate(today.getDate() + i))
</script>
```

Then update the `v-for` to render it:

```html
<template>
  <span v-for="date in nextSevenDays">{{ date }}</span>
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-generate-week-ahead?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FWeekAhead.vue)